# RestKit how to build checkout from Git Repo?

Tags: restkit, rkobjectmapping

I've checked out the RestKit repo and after a pod install in the top level folder attempting to build the tests and or the project fails. I've fixed some missing dependencies that still point to vendor but get a build fail in RKObjectMapping.h due to RKValueTransformers.h not found. What steps are needed to build the tests and the library in the workspace from the git repo?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: Solution from and thanks to Blake Watters is to do git update submodules before attempting anything else.